# update data in oracle database by using netbeans

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I want to update data in oracle database using JFrame text fields in netbeans but it is not going to updated and there is no error showing but date is also not updating.

```
private void updateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    conn = javadb.ConnectDb();

    try{
        String sql = "UPDATE addbook SET title=?, author=?, accno=?  WHERE isbn = ?";
        pst = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, updatetitle.getText());
        pst.setString(2, updateisbn.getText());
        pst.setString(3, updateauthor.getText());
        pst.setString(4, updateaccno.getText());
        pst.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Book information Updated!");

    }catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    update_table();

}
```

And I want to select data from database by giving its title which code is here

```
private void update_table() {
    try {

        String sql = "SELECT * from addbook where isbn=?";
        pst = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, selisbn.getText());
        rs = (OracleResultSet) pst.executeQuery();
        addtable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

It is working fine and set data to a table but i want to set it to text fields and so that user can make changes and update it.

Comment: What is `addtable`? Where do you populate you text fields?

Comment: addtable is the name of netbeans Swing table's name. And i am using DbUtilities for it do show oracle table into my application.